# Adding XML nodes with loop

Tags: c#, xml, loops

How should I redefine parent `<address>` node and add children `<addressline line="">` to it with attributes, based on my loop parameters.
At the moment I only add data to the `<address>` node.

Current code:

```
public class PDFXml {

        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public string Filepath { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        //redefine Address node and add children
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int PostIndex { get; set; }

        public void CreateXML(string pdfPath, string savePath) {

            HeaderInfo headerinfo = new HeaderInfo();


            var pdfxmldata = new PDFXml() {
                Filename = Path.GetFileName(pdfPath),
                Filepath = pdfPath,
                Name = headerinfo.GetFullName(pdfPath).Trim(),
                //Address = "??????????",
                PostIndex = headerinfo.GetPostIndex(pdfPath),
            };

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                //Add addressline element to <address> - <addressline line = "i"></addressline>
            }

            var filestream = new FileStream(savePath + @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pdfPath) + ".xml", FileMode.Create);
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(PDFXml)).Serialize(filestream, pdfxmldata);
            filestream.Close();

        }
    }
```

My current XML

```
<pdfxml>
    <filename></filename>
    <filepath></filepath>

    <name></name>
    <address></address>
    <index></index>
</pdfxml>
```

I would like something like this:

```
<pdfxml>
    <filename></filename>
    <filepath></filepath>

    <name></name>

    <address>
       <addressline line="1" ></addressline>
       <addressline line="2" ></addressline>
       ...
       <addressline line="999" ></addressline>
    </address>
    <index></index>
</pdfxml>
```

Comment: You can read the entire xml into a string and then use XDocument to add new child nodes to it in your loop. Finally read all InnerXml/InnerText from the XDocument and save to the File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce new classes:

```
public class AddressLine
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("line")]
    public int Line { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [XmlElement("addressline")]
    public List<AddressLine> AddressLines { get; set; }
}
```

Change property of PDFXml to:

```
//Changed Address to AddressL
public Address AddressL { get; set; }
```

Create instance like this:

```
//Changed Address to AddressL
var pdfxmldata = new PDFXml()
{
    ...
    AddressL = new Address { AddressLines = new List<AddressLine>() },
    ...
};
```

Fill data as follows:

```
//Changed Address to AddressL
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    pdfxmldata.AddressL.AddressLines.Add(new AddressLine { Line = i, Text = "Some address" });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Address in new pdfxmldata be something different? Because it gets into conflict with class called Address. Otherwise it worked out great! Thank You!